# Using Tortoise SVN, how can I download the latest version of the source code of my CodePlex application?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, codeplex

I'm trying to figure out how to download the latest source code.

Here's what I've done.

1. On my desktop machine, I created my CodePlex app account, installed Tortoise SVN and successfully uploaded my code to the site. The source code now shows on the CodePlex site.
2. On my **laptop**, I installed Tortoise SVN. I then created a blank folder and I'm now trying to download the code available on my CodePlex site.

I know my SVN url, and my user name and password.

I'm just lost as to how to do it. I try *SVN Update*, but it only downloads a couple of files, not the complete source code.

Comment: It's still not a programming question if you ask me.

Comment: It's related to programming in the highest way. Don't transfer it please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Tortoise simply Right-Click in your Directory and do an "SVN Checkout.." This option is directly above your "Tortoise SVN" menu.

Comment: I can't find that option. Check my screenshot.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to create an entirely new folder and then do the checkout. I'm going to ask a related question, so please check it out. :D

Comment: In the last version appear: "SVN Upate"

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "SVN Update" 
try "TortoiseSVN->Update to Revision..." 
and select "Update Depth=Fully recursive".

Answer (score 2):

When starting with no code on the laptop, run SVN Checkout the first time, this creates a working copy.

SVN Update should be run on this working copy (or subpaths). It's normal for update to fetch only a few files, as it only fetches the modifications

Comment: Hi Sander, is the folder updated automagically or do I have to manually run the update?

Comment: You have to manually run the update. It pretty much needs to work like that, as the alternative introduces far too many potential problems with people breaking something other people were relying on - it would be far too painful to figure out what went wrong, because you wouldn't know where the error originated - you couldn't tell if it broke before or after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder you want to create the files to, then go up, right click *on the folder*, and choose "SVN Checkout" from the menu. Then enter your URL repository.

If you don't see that menu option TortoiseSVN must not have installed correctly.