# Using SVN am I obligated to create a new folder and do the checkout without exception?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Refer to my previous question for context: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024437/using-tortoise-svn-how-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-the-source-code-of-m)

Consider this situation:

1. I upload the source code for my app for the very first time from my Desktop.
2. On my laptop machine, I create a blank folder and do the Checkout.
3. Two days pass and while working on my Desktop I decide to scrap the entire project. I delete everything in the Repo by deleting everything in the folder (in Windows Explorer) and then doing a SVN Commit.
4. My laptop still has the previous version on Hard Drive correct? But when I do an SVN Update (ie. I think it's supposed to delete everything in my folder on my Hard Drive and enable my folder for SVN magic) a couple of files are *downloaded. It's not working as intended, I guess.

   5. I have to create a **entirely new folder in Windows Explorer** and do the SVN Checkout. Now it's working properly.

Can anyone let me know why this is made this way? SVN Checkout isn't available for an already checked-out folder?

*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually *commit* the deletes? (You might need to check them in the TortiseSVN interface). It seems like that did not happen correctly; because if it did the update would result in the removal of the files, as you suggest (it seems like you did though, because the later 'Checkout' worked).

Otherwise, the only other option is that the desktop folder you refer to isn't pointing where you think it is (you can do a 'browse repository' to figure out where it points).

Answer (score 1):

Use the TortoiseSVN context menu Delete (in Windows Explorer) and then commit, don't just delete the files using the standard Windows Explorer Delete.

Comment: While it's preferable, you don't need to do this; TortiseSVN will still detect the removal of deleted files and let you commit them. (commit them being 'deleted').

Comment: Well, not quite as easily, the files you delete show up as 'Missing', not as 'Deleted' and also are not selected by default when performing a commit (which may well have led to OP's problem in the first place!) . Though indeed when you explicitly check them they will be deleted from the repository.

Comment: You can get away with manually deleting files but you can get in a real mess if you manually delete folders - much cleaner to use the TortoiseSVN context menu.